# How to convert and display html from a json file to xaml with xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, html, xaml, xamarin.forms

I'm using C# with xamarin forms to build an android app. I hard coded the xaml but can access the html from an SDK. What is the best way to display this html as xaml?

I have stored in the following object, the string  value of a json file

`dynamic dynamicObject  = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data.ToString());`
when running `Console.WriteLine(dynamicObject.mainText)`
where `mainText` is the json property and logs it's value as the html

```html
<div style="font-family:sans-serif;">
  <p> some text </p>
  <p> some more text </p>
  <p><a href = "google.com">here's google<a/>
  </p>
</div>
```

Instead of individually binding the values of the html elements to our xaml file elements, is there a way to parse/convert all the code to xaml or how is the best way to display the html?

Comment: you can display HTML in a webview or a Label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### WebView

create a `HtmlWebViewSource` .

```
WebView webview = new WebView();
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = dynamicObject.mainText;
webview.Source = htmlSource;
```

##### Label

set TextType  as `Html`.

```
Label label = new Label();
label.Text = dynamicObject.mainText;
label.TextType = TextType.Html;
```